# how to combine 2 access database table

Tags: ms-access

I have a access database which includes `tblSO` and `tblSO_archive` tables.

I want to combine this two tables. The tables have the same columns and column names.

I tried **INTERSECT** and **UNION** but it doesn't work for me. Is there any suggestion? When I try **UNION** it gives me **too many columns** error.

Table 1
[image]

Table 2
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question (edit)!, e,g, sample data as [formatted text table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: And search on your title for solution ;)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I searched my title but I didn't find any solution for me so I asked this question.

Comment: First SO result on DuckDuckGo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546717/merging-two-tables-in-access.

Answer (score 1):

Create dummy fields for the ones that don't have a corresponding match with the other table.

```
SELECT strSO, strTSN FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT strSO, '' FROM Table2
```

Comment: My tables have 156 columns, so do I need to create dummy field for each columns?